# Integral Over Homotopic paths

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, contour-integration

My complex analysis textbook stated the following proposition:

> Let $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ be two closed paths in the complex plain. If there exists an homotopy between these two paths, then:
> $$\oint_\Gamma f=\oint_{\Gamma'}f$$

---

I came up with the following example:

Let $$f = \frac{g(z)}{z  - a}$$

Then we have that

$$\oint_\Gamma \frac{g(z)}{z  - a} =\oint_{\Gamma'}\frac{g(z)}{z  - a}$$

Using Cauchy integral formula we end up with:

$$2 \pi i\  g(a) \text{Ind}_\Gamma(a)= 2 \pi i\  g(a) \text{Ind}_{\Gamma'}(a)$$

Witch is equal to:

$$ \text{Ind}_\Gamma(a) =  \text{Ind}_{\Gamma'}(a)$$

But this is not necessarily true. There could be some point $a$ that is in the interior of $\Gamma$, hence $\text{Ind}_\Gamma(a) = 1$ but after the homotopy it end up outside $\Gamma'$, hence $\text{Ind}_{\Gamma'}(a) = 0$. What is going on there? Did I make any mistake?

Comment: You need the homotopy to avoid singularities of the integrand.

Comment: Why? @AnginaSeng

Comment: @Eduude because you didn't state the theorem correctly.

Comment: Check "Theorem 0.1" in this PDF: https://math.berkeley.edu/~vvdatar/m185f16/notes/Lecture-12_Homotopies.pdf

Is that implied in the fact that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in that domain? @user10354138

Comment: In that theorem, the homotopy between $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ need to stay inside $\Omega$ (this is what it means to be "homotopic in $\Omega$"). In particular, in your example, the homotopy between $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ is not allowed to sweep through the singularity $a$ (which cannot be contained in $\Omega$), therefore the indices of the curves remain the same.

Comment: Homotopies need to be continuous, thats the whole point about them (: